# "cannot access ppa" trying to download ubuntu sdk

Tags: 12.04, ppa, downloads, ubuntu-sdk, sdk

I was trying to download Ubuntu sdk entering:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-sdk`

However, the answer was `Cannot acces ppa, please check your internet connection`, which I did by pinging google. My internet connection was fine.
I also tryed swapping `add-apt` to `apt-add` which didn't work either.

Does someone know an answer?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using ?

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention that: 12.04lts

Comment: Hi, try running "sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa" first, then if that works "sudo apt-get update" so we can try and narrow down which step the error is occurring.

Comment: mh i did as you said and right the first line failed, but then the terminal got stuck and i closed and started it again, tried the same again and this time it worked perfectly. No idea where the mistake was..
Thank you anyways!

Comment: Sounds like you have a connectivity issue.